# How to use shift, reduce, error, accept and conflict keywords in lex or yacc in c++?

Tags: c++, yacc, lex

What are the meanings of these keywords:

`shift`, `reduce`, `error`, `accept`, `conflict`?

Please give a full description of each.

```
switch ( oAction)
{
   case SSYaccAction::shift:
      oElement = shift( lookahead());
      if ( !oElement) return SSTrue;
      oElement->oLexeme = lookahead();
      oElement->oulState = state();
      push();
      if ( getLexeme()) return SSTrue;
      oulError++;
      break;
   case SSYaccAction::reduce:
     oElement = reduce( production(), productionSize());
      if ( !oElement) return SSTrue;
      pop( productionSize());
      if ( goTo( leftside())) return SSTrue;
      break;
   case SSYaccAction::error:
      oError = SSTrue;
      if ( error( state(), lookahead()))
         return SSTrue;
      oulError = 0;
      break;
   case SSYaccAction::accept:
      return accept();
   default:
      throwException( SSExceptionYaccParse, SSYaccMsgParse);
      return SSTrue;
```

In the above code, what are the meanings of

```
lookahead()
```

and

```
reduce(production(), productionSize())
```

Comment: Have you tried reading the Yacc [documentation](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/yacc/) ? This contains a clear explanation of the above, and a lot of other information to get you started.

Comment: Sorry, the link was wrong, I have updated it now!

Comment: Sorry, there is no link...please add

Comment: Click on the word "documentation" in my comment above :)

Answer (score 0):

([Answered in the comments.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments))

@KLibby wrote:

> Have you tried reading the Yacc [documentation](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/yacc/) ? This contains a clear explanation of the above, and a lot of other information to get you started.